# Как перемещать виджет внутри layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Мне нужно четкое расположение виджетов с возможностью изменять размер окна. Для этого я добавил layouts и в них виджеты, но после этого на виджеты не работает ни move(), ни setGeometry(). Соответсвенно они находятся там где мне это не надо

Цель:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что у меня выходит:
[image: Что я имею]

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        # self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.resize(1300, 800)

        self.wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid)

        self.name1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.name1.setObjectName("name1")
        self.name1.move(70, 170)

        self.dolor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.dolor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 235, 140, 35))
        self.dolor.setObjectName("dolor")

        self.boolp = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.boolp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 235, 140, 35))
        self.boolp.setObjectName("boolp")
        self.boolp.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

        self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 290, 115, 30))
        self.Button1.setObjectName("Button1")
        self.Button1.setText("OK!")

        self.nametext = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.dolortext = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.sizetext = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

        self.nametext.setText("lorem ipsum")
        self.nametext.setGeometry(75, 147, 100, 20)

        self.dolortext.setText("dolor")
        self.dolortext.setGeometry(75, 212, 100, 20)

        self.sizetext.setText("sit amet")
        self.sizetext.setGeometry(235, 212, 100, 20)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addStretch(1)

        for each in [self.Button1, self.name1, self.boolp, self.dolor, self.nametext, self.dolortext, self.sizetext]:
            self.layout.addWidget(each)

        self.wid.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Comment: `ни move(), ни setGeometry().` компоновщики как раз и создавались, чтобы программист не указывал руками положение и размер виджетов, и это правильно сделано. Если вам это не нужно, то уберите компоновщики, а у виджетов указывайте в качестве родителя виджет, на котором их нужно разместить, тогда move/setGeometry будут работать. Если вам нужен фиксированный размер виджета в компоновщике, то используйте функции setFixedSize|Width|Height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно: вы создали горизонтальный layout и поместли туда все ваши элементы, они сответственно выстроились горизонтально. Layout - самоорганизующийся элемент: Вертикальный - выстраивает внутренние элементы в столбец, горизонтальный - в строку. Если вам нужен результат как на первой картинке: задайте основной вертикальный layout для MainWindow и в него поместите 3 горизонтальных layoutа, внутри которых разместите ваши виджеты. Можете еще задать нужные отступы. Тогда, при изменении размера окна подстроятся и внутренние элементы.

Comment: Еще возникает ошибка при запуске QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "", which already has a layout. Не подскажите?

Comment: @whyeaye ну судя по тексту ошибки вы добавляете лэйаут туда где он уже есть, значит лэйаут надо добавить не рядом, а в другой лэйаут?

Answer (score 0):

По поводу основной вашей ошибки достаточно ясно написал @gil9red.

Также необходимо понимать, что когда вы публикуете пример надо видеть
все что вы отображаете в окне, а не фрагмент. 
Тогда будет легче дать вам правильный ответ.

Вот вам пример, который демонстрирует некоторые возможность **QGridLayout**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()    
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        frame1 = self.createFormGroupBox()
        frame2 = self.createFormFrame2()
        frame3 = self.createFormFrame3()

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        mainLayout.addWidget(frame1, 0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter) 
        mainLayout.addWidget(frame2, 0, 1) 
        mainLayout.addWidget(frame3, 1, 0, 1, 2) 
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Frame 1", objectName="formGroupBox")
        layout = QGridLayout(formGroupBox)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20, 30, 20, 30)

        nametext   = QtWidgets.QLabel("lorem ipsum")
        self.name1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(nametext)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.name1)
        layout.addLayout(layoutV, 0, 0)

        dolortext = QtWidgets.QLabel("dolor")
        self.dolor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)        
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(dolortext)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.dolor)
        layout.addLayout(layoutV, 1, 0)

        sizetext = QtWidgets.QLabel("sit amet")
        self.boolp = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.boolp.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.boolp.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])       
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(sizetext)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.boolp)
        layout.addLayout(layoutV, 1, 1)

        self.buttonOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK!")
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonOk, 2, 0)
        return formGroupBox

    def createFormFrame2(self):
        self.formGroupBox2 = QGroupBox("Frame 2", objectName="formGroupBox2")
        layout = QGridLayout(self.formGroupBox2)
        layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10) 
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelSetPixmap()
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        return self.formGroupBox2    

    def createFormFrame3(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(14, 7)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        return self.tableWidget 

    def labelSetPixmap(self):
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(
                                                       self.width() / 2, 
                                                       self.height() / 2, 
                                                       Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation
                                                     )
        )

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(MainWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.labelSetPixmap()


StyleSheet = '''
#formGroupBox { 
    background-color : #ccd;
}
#formGroupBox2 { 
    background-color : #3cd;
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
    w.resize(800, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]